# Pandas: select all dates with specific month and day

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have a dataframe full of dates and I would like to select all dates where the month==12 and the day==25 and add replace the zero in the `xmas` column with a 1.

Anyway to do this? the second line of my code errors out.

```
df = DataFrame({'date':[datetime(2013,1,1).date() + timedelta(days=i) for i in range(0,365*2)], 'xmas':np.zeros(365*2)})

df[df['date'].month==12 and df['date'].day==25] = 1
```

Comment: You want this: `df.loc[(df['date'].month==12) & (df['date'].day==25), 'xmas'] = 1`

Comment: Just so this gets more easily seen, you now have the datetime atribute, allowing you to write something like `df['date'].dt.month == 12`.

Answer (score 40):

Pandas `Series` with datetime now behaves differently. See [.dt accessor](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#basics-dt-accessors).

This is how it should be done now:

```
df.loc[(df['date'].dt.day==25) & (cust_df['date'].dt.month==12), 'xmas'] = 1
```

Answer (score 15):

Basically what you tried won't work as you need to use the `&` to compare arrays, additionally you need to use parentheses due to operator precedence. On top of this you should use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html) to perform the indexing:

```
df.loc[(df['date'].month==12) & (df['date'].day==25), 'xmas'] = 1
```

Comment: My experience gave me an error about the column name but I just used `df.index` in place of `df['date']` and then it worked as you've shown.

Comment: What about more than one month eg if month is 6 ,7 8 9, then?

Answer (score 2):

An update was needed in reply to this question. As of today, there's a slight difference in how you extract months from datetime objects in a pd.Series.

So from the very start, incase you have a raw date column, first convert it to datetime objects by using a simple function:

```
import datetime as dt
def read_as_datetime(str_date):
    # replace %Y-%m-%d with your own date format
    return dt.datetime.strptime(str_date,'%Y-%m-%d')
```

then apply this function to your dates column and save results in a new column namely datetime:

```
df['datetime'] = df.dates.apply(read_as_datetime)
```

finally in order to extract dates by day and month, use the same piece of code that @Shayan RC explained, with this slight change; notice the dt.datetime after calling the datetime column:

```
df.loc[(df['datetime'].dt.datetime.month==12) &(df['datetime'].dt.datetime.day==25),'xmas'] =1
```