# Slicing pandas dataframe by custom months and days -- is there a way to avoid for loops?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time-series

#### The problem

Suppose I have a time series dataframe `df` (a `pandas` dataframe) and some days I want to slice from it, contained in another dataframe called `sample_days`:

```
>>> df

                          foo       bar
2020-01-01 00:00:00  0.360049  0.897839
2020-01-01 01:00:00  0.285667  0.409544
2020-01-01 02:00:00  0.323871  0.240926
2020-01-01 03:00:00  0.921623  0.766624
2020-01-01 04:00:00  0.087618  0.142409
...                       ...       ...
2020-12-31 19:00:00  0.145111  0.993822
2020-12-31 20:00:00  0.331223  0.021287
2020-12-31 21:00:00  0.531099  0.859035
2020-12-31 22:00:00  0.759594  0.790265
2020-12-31 23:00:00  0.103651  0.074029

[8784 rows x 2 columns]
```

```
>>> sample_days

   month  day
0      3   16
1      7   26
2      8   15
3      9   26
4     11   25
```

I want to slice `df` with the days specified in `sample_days`. I can do this with for loops (see below). However, is there a way to avoid for loops (as this is more efficient)? The result should be a dataframe called `sample` like the following:

```
>>> sample

                          foo       bar
2020-03-16 00:00:00  0.707276  0.592614
2020-03-16 01:00:00  0.136679  0.357872
2020-03-16 02:00:00  0.612331  0.290126
2020-03-16 03:00:00  0.276389  0.576996
2020-03-16 04:00:00  0.612977  0.781527
...                       ...       ...
2020-11-25 19:00:00  0.904266  0.825501
2020-11-25 20:00:00  0.269589  0.050304
2020-11-25 21:00:00  0.271814  0.418235
2020-11-25 22:00:00  0.595005  0.973198
2020-11-25 23:00:00  0.151149  0.024057

[120 rows x 2 columns
```

which is just the `df` sliced across the correct days.

#### My (slow) solution

I've managed to do this using for loops and `pd.concat`:

```
sample = pd.concat([df.loc[df.index.month.isin([sample_day.month]) &
                           df.index.day.isin([sample_day.day])] 
                    for sample_day in sample_days.itertuples()])
```

which is based on concatenating multiple days as sliced by the method indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28569461/pandas-select-all-dates-with-specific-month-and-day?noredirect=1&lq=1). This gives the desired result but is rather slow. For example, using this method to get the first day of each month takes 0.2 seconds on average, whereas just calling `df.loc[df.index.day == 1]` (presumably avoiding python for loops under-the-hood) is around 300 times faster. However, this is a slice on just the day -- I am slicing on month and day.

Apologies if this has been answered somewhere else -- I've searched for quite a while but perhaps was not using the correct keywords.

Comment: "ways other than for loops" isn't always more efficient.  Often, the alternative is just a loop in disguise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting a bit of inspiration from @Ben Pap's solution (thanks!), I've found a solution that is both fast and avoids any "hacks" like changing datetime to strings. It combines the month and day into a single MultiIndex, as below (you can make this a single line, but I've expanded it into multiple to make the idea clear).

```
full_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df.index.month, df.index.day],
                                       names=['month', 'day'])
sample_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(sample_days)
sample = df.loc[full_index.isin(sample_index)]
```

If I run this code along with my original for loop and @Ben Pap's answer, and sample 100 days from one year time series for 2020 (8784 hours with the leap day), I get the following solution times:

- Original for loop: 0.16s
- @Ben Pap's solution, combining month and day into single string: 0.019s
- Above solution using MultiIndex: 0.006s

so I think using a MultiIndex is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a string comparison of the month and days at the same time.

You need the space to differentiate between `11 2` and `1 12` for example, otherwise both would be regarded as the same.

```
df.loc[(df.index.month.astype(str) +' '+ df.index.day.astype(str)).isin(sample_days['month'].astype(str)+' '+sample_days['day'].astype(str))]
```